# Display some values in string Angular/Typescript

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have json format like that. How can I display hobbies without the word "all" in Angular/TypeScript?

```
 {
    "Name": "Mustermann1",
    "Vorname": "Max1",
    "maennlich": true,
    "Hobbys": ["Reiten", "Golfen", "Lesen", "all"],
    "Alter": 42,
    "Kinder": [],
    "Partner": null
 }
 {
    "Name": "Mustermann2",
    "Vorname": "Max2",
    "maennlich": true,
    "Hobbys": ["Reiten", "Golfen", "Lesen"],
    "Alter": 42,
    "Kinder": [],
    "Partner": null
 }
 {
    "Name": "Mustermann3",
    "Vorname": "Max3",
    "maennlich": true,
    "Hobbys": ["Reiten", "Lesen", "all"],
    "Alter": 42,
    "Kinder": [],
    "Partner": null
  }
```

Comment: Do you want to add it to your template?

Comment: @MirentafazAli: I want to show all names with Hobbys, which includes Hobbys "Reiten" or "Golfen" or "Lesen" (Without "All") in HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data = data.map((val) => {
      val.Hobbys = val.Hobbys.filter((x) => x !== 'all');
      return val;
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with two `*ngFor` loops and one `*ngIf` in your HTML, given that you have the data coming from your component. *It might not be the ideal way to do it.*

You loop through each person and each hobby to show, and filter out any hobby that is `'all'`.

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="hobby !== 'all'">
    {{ hobby }}
</ng-container>
```

A quick setup:

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let person of dataObject">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <h3>Name: {{ person.Vorname }}</h3>
      <ng-container *ngFor="let hobby of person.Hobbys">
        <ng-container *ngIf="hobby !== 'all'">
          {{ hobby }}
        </ng-container>
      </ng-container>
    </li>
  </ul>
</ng-container>
```

[image: Result of StackBlitz]

[And a working StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-42hzys?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) to validate your needs.

Answer (score 1):

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of items">
  <ng-container *ngIf="item.Hobbys.indexOf('all') < 0">
    <ul>
      <li>
        {{ item.Name }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

[image: here is output]

[stackblitz code link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-sbqfhi?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)